# Resolving multiple static method calls

Tags: php, static-methods

I have a static method that returns a fully name-spaced class identifier. I would like to be able to call a static method of said class in a one-liner like so:

```
static::CLASSES('\name\spaced\Foo')::bar();
```

I assume I have some resolution problem of some sort. I have been playing around with `{}`, but could not get it to work.

If possible I don't want to do the following (which works):

```
$foo = static::CLASSES('\name\spaced\Foo');
$foo::bar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `static::CLASSES('\name\spaced\Foo')->bar();`

If the first expression returns an instance then you are going to call an instance method

**UPDATE**

Now that the first method is returning a classname as opposed to a instance method I believe

```
call_user_func(array(static::CLASSES('\name\spaced\Foo'), "bar"));
```

or with parameters

```
call_user_func_array(array(static::CLASSES('\name\spaced\Foo'), "bar"), $paramArray);
```

May show you some love

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thank you. I need this to be a static call. I changed it so that `static::CLASSES('\name\spaced\Foo')` now returns a fully namespaced class name, but static::CLASSES('\name\spaced\Foo')::bar() still gives me a compiler error.

Comment: updated the answer to show usage of static method form of call_user_func_array.